# Can a single layer network approximate an arbitrary function?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks

Can [a network with a single layer](http://wwwold.ece.utep.edu/research/webfuzzy/docs/kk-thesis/kk-thesis-html/node15.html) of $N$ neurons (where $N \le \infty$, no hidden layers) approximate any arbitrary function so that this network’s error approaches 0 as $N$ approaches $\infty$?

Comment: "no hidden layers" --> trick question

Comment: I don't understand why this is closed as off-topic. Sounds like a clear on-topic question to me. I vote to reopen.

Comment: That said, if your arbitrary function is a function from some input into real numbers, then you *must* have only 1 output neuron, so it's not clear what do you mean by the output N approaching infinity. Your single layer network is just a linear combination of a bunch of inputs passed through a specified nonlinearity (e.g. sigmoid). That's all. One output neuron. The number of input neurons is given by the problem, it can't be modified at all.

Comment: @amoeba please read the [original revision](https://stats.stackexchange.com/revisions/366096/1) and you will understand.

Comment: @Firebug That's why I edited the question, so it would conform with the rules and not be closed

Comment: @user Sorry, I see you're trying to be helpful. But that does not change the fact that the question is suspiciously similar to homework. We put these questions on hold so the asker can familiarize him/herself with the site rules. After all, the answers are supposed to be useful to the asking person first and foremost.

Comment: @Firebug I personally don't care much one way or the other, but I thought that if you could rephrase the question to be more helpful to other readers it would be ok. In any case, great job of the moderators in this site, so whatever the decision, it will be good.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

False: If there are no hidden layers, then your neural network will only be able to approximate linear functions, not any continuous function.

In fact, you need at least one hidden layer for a solution to the simple xor problem (see this [post](http://machinethink.net/blog/the-hello-world-of-neural-networks/) and this [one](https://medium.com/@jayeshbahire/the-xor-problem-in-neural-networks-50006411840b)).

When you only have an input and an output layer, and no hidden layer, the output layer is just a linear function of its weights since the activation function only acts on the inner product of the input with the weights, hence you can only produce linearly separable solutions.

N.B. It does not matter what your activation function are, the point is that no neural net with no hidden layer can solve the xor problem, since its solutions are non-linearly separable.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82993/discussion-on-answer-by-user-single-layer-neural-network).

Comment: The first sentence is wrong (-1) because neurons in the output layer can be nonlinear.

Comment: @amobea that is still a very small class of functions (non-linear after a single linear transformation), so while technically wrong it is only because of a technicality. If you add an arbitrary nonlinear transformation, you are restricted to single-index models.

Comment: @amoeba You are wrong, no matter what the neurons in the output layer are, it will never learn to separate non-linearly separable points, see the xor example. You should not confuse the reader with wrong statements.

Comment: I never said anything about xor. What I said is that if the output neuron is nonlinear then clearly the function that the neural network will represent will be nonlinear too. Example: one input neuron, $x$. One output neuron with sigmoid nonlinearity. Neural network learns $f(x) = \text{sigmoid}(wx+b)$. Nonlinear function.

Comment: @amoeba For a network to be linear, it means it is able to solve non-linear problems, like xor. I repeat, a network with no hidden layer can only solve linear problems. This has nothing to do with the choice of the output function.

Comment: Okay, so we are talking about different things: you are talking about linearly separable classification problems, and I am talking about network output as a function of its inputs. I still think your first sentence ("your neural network will only be able to approximate linear functions") implies "my" meaning and not "yours". If you edit to clarify this bit I will gladly remove the downvote.

Answer (score 3):

The **[Universal Approximation Theorem](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Universal_approximation_theorem)** states that a neural network with one hidden layer can approximate continuous functions on compact subsets of $R^n$, so no, not *any* arbitrary function.

Comment: A single-layer network is not equivalent to a neural network with one hidden layer if I understand it correctly.

Comment: If he is talking about only having the output layer, i.e. without the hidden layer, it also can't model the function set described in the theorem.

Comment: A NN with one hidden layer has a total of 2 layers, while a single-layer network looks something like this: http://wwwold.ece.utep.edu/research/webfuzzy/docs/kk-thesis/kk-thesis-html/node15.html

Comment: The universal approximation theorems say that functions in a specified class can be approximated by networks of a specified class. They don't state what happens outside of these conditions (e.g. that other functions can't be approximated). So, I don't think this answers the question.

Comment: "A well-known theorem says X, so a more general version Y is false" is not really a proper mathematical argument.

Comment: However, failing to fit "any arbitrary function" with one hidden layer directly mean that you cannot fit those functions without a hidden layer.